# Is a set that's open in a topology still open in the subspace topology? What about closed?

Tags: general-topology

watching a lecture I missed, and there's a subspace
$$Y\subset X$$ given the subspace topology, and a clopen (in $X$) set $A$, and a point $p$ in both $A$ and $Y$ (unsure if this is relevant or not to this question, but they do share at least one point in common).
Then, the professor writes that $A$ is clopen in $Y$ because $A$ is clopen in $X$ and $Y$ is given the subspace topology.

But, I don't understand why exactly this is. Because, isn't $A\cap Y$ just a subset of $A$, and subsets of open spaces can be closed sometimes and vice versa. So, why does this hold?

Edit: Oh wait, immediately after posting, I remembered that a set in the subspace topology is declared to be open if it's the union of $Y$ and some open set in $X$, and the same for closed sets. Is that why?

Comment: If $A \subseteq Y$ and $A$ is clopen in $X$ then it's also clopen in $Y$. Use that $A \cap Y=A$ in this case.

Comment: In the last paragraph it's not union but intersection you want BTW.

Answer (score 1):

> I remembered that a set in the subspace topology is declared to be open if it's the union of $Y$ and some open set in $X$, and the same for closed sets. Is that why?

Not union, but intersection. Yes, that's exactly why.

Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y\subseteq X$. By definition open subsets of $Y$ are precisely those of the form $U\cap Y$ for open subset $U$ of $X$. And closed subsets of $Y$ are precisely subsets of the form $F\cap Y$ for closed subset $F$ of $X$.

And so if $F$ is clopen in $X$ then $F\cap Y$ is both open and closed in $Y$ by definition. Thus clopen as well.